# Does a Python module ever change functionality (due to source code changes) after it is first imported

Tags: python, compilation

I have a Python script which

1. calls a function `foo` which imports and uses module `my_module`
2. does some lengthy calculations
3. calls a function `bar` which also imports and uses module `my_module`

If `my_module.py` is changed at some point during step 2, will `bar` always use the same `my_module` that was used in  `foo` ?

What if I run another Python script during step 2. that also imports `my_module`?

I created the toy scenarios above, and it seems like `my_module` indeed stays the same for all its calls in the original Pythons script, but I'd like to have a guarantee for that or know situations in which it could fail.

(Background: This is for scientific software development. I write an algorithm, commit to git, run it to see if it works and what it produces, and while waiting for it to finish continue working on its source. If I don't like the results, I'd like to know what exact source was responsible for the results.)

Comment: If you edit the *file*, not unless something explicitly `reload`s the module; it's stored in memory once, when first imported.

Comment: Modules are loaded into memory *just once*. It doesn't matter if the source file changed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Doesn't the question that you listed as duplicate address the opposite problem? I actually had read that other question before, but there, the modules are supposed to be reloaded and the answers provide ways to guarantee that they are. As far as I understood, that does not imply that without importlib.reload the modules are never changed. Anyway, your comment does say so, so thanks for the answer

Comment: @Bananach: that post exists *because* modules don't reload on their own. Had there been other paths to reloading (such as editing the source file) those would have been documented there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters There could have been options that do not guarantee a reload but that pose a risk(nonzero chance) of a reload. Those options would have not been suitable as answers there, but they would have been important to about for me

Comment: there are no such options. The full process is documented at https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html; modules are searched for in `sys.modules` first, if present there then no loading takes place, see [*5.3.1. The module cache*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-module-cache)